# SQL Bigquery : Limiting the selection from a particular group to 10

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Below is the sample table

Currently the table has unlimited entries for each ID.

My requirement is, to first sort the IDs in the ascending order of rand. Then take only the first 2 rows ['ID' and 'companies'.]

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    ID int,
    companies varchar(255),
    rand float(2)
);

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1, 'a', 0.2);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1, 'b', 0.6);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (2, 'a', 0.4);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (2, 'b', 0.5);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (2, 'c', 0.3);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (3, 'a', 0.6);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (3, 'b', 0.7);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (3, 'c', 0.4);
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (3, 'd', 0.2);
```

i.e for the final table should contain only at max 2 rows per ID. (need not contain rand column)

Comment: Do you know which two rows you want?  Why would you want duplicate rows (which is the case without the `rand` column?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need the top 2 values of 'rand'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want `row_number()`?

```
select * except(rn)
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by rand) rn
    from table_name t
) t
where rn <= 2
```

This selects maximum two records per `id`, which have the samllest `rand`; you can arrange the `order by` clause of `row_number()` to your actual sorting criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT rec.* FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(id, companies) ORDER BY rand LIMIT 2) arr 
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t
  GROUP BY id
), UNNEST(arr) rec
```

if to apply to sample data from  your example - output is

```
Row id  companies    
1   1   a    
2   1   b    
3   2   c    
4   2   a    
5   3   d    
6   3   c
```